# Political Negotiation

Tags: international-relations

Since the nuclear talks between Iran and Group 5+1 are in progress, and since these talks have been extended in the past year, I was wondering what exactly is going on inside the room with these kinds of political negotiations? How are these negotiations being conducted, and what is everybody talking about?

I have very little prior knowledge about Politics and no background about the political negotiation techniques, strategies, skills and history. Could you please recommend a good elementary book on the subject?

Comment: High level: you offer concessions that have as little as possible negative effect on you, but can be sold to your opponents sheeple as big breakthrough. (at least if you're an authoritarian/strong-central government negotiating with a democracy, as is the case here)

Comment: This kind of open-ended political question isn't a good suit for the stackexchange model. If you have a specific question about the negotiations then you can ask it, but if you want general information about what's going on, check out wikipedia.